# How to rebuild the libmem_crc32_direct CRC function in python?

Tags: python, c, stm32, crc

I like to rebuild the [`libmem_crc32_direct`](https://www.rowleydownload.co.uk/arm/documentation/libmem_crc32_direct.htm) function in python.

I used the `crcmod` python package before. So I like to setup the crc generator by using it.

the c-code looks like:

```
uint32_t crc_process_chunk(uint8_t* data, uint32_t len) {
  return ~libmem_crc32_direct(data, len, 0xFFFFFFFF);
}
```

my python code looks so far:

```
def bit_not(n, numbits=8):
    return (1 << numbits) - 1 - n

def getCRC(imageBA):
    crcGen = crcmod.mkCrcFun(0x104C11DB7, initCrc=0xFFFFFFFF)
    val = crcGen(imageBA)
    val = bit_not(val, 32)
    return val
```

The returned value of the python code is not equal of the one in c. So I guess I mad some error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

B bit tricky because 64Bit arithmetic on PC vs 32Bit arithmetic on ARM STM32F4, but finally this solution works:

```
def libmem_crc32_direct_with_xor(im, startAddr, l):
    fw = im[startAddr:startAddr+l]
    crcGen =  crcmod.Crc(0x104C11DB7, initCrc=0xFFFFFFFF, rev = False)
    crcGen.update(fw)
    return (~crcGen.crcValue ) & 0xFFFFFFFF # 32bit xor
```

Comment: You can use input parameter xorOut = 0xFFFFFFFF instead of complementing the crc in the return.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't (1 << numbits) == 0?  If this is two's complement math it should work as bit_not could be return 0-1-n. However, this isn't needed, since there is an optional xorOut parameter for crcmod. I'm thinking that since the optional rev parameter for reversed (reflected) input and output defaults to true, it needs to be set to false. I think the call to create the crc generator should be:

```
    crcGen = crcmod.mkCrcFun(0x104C11DB7, initCrc=0xFFFFFFF, rev=False, xorOut=0xFFFFFFFF)
```